# Page scroll stops on <select multiple> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, scroll

I have a standard `<select multiple>...</select>` option list on a page that scrolls.  When scrolling through the document, particularly with a trackpad, the page stops once the pointer is over the `<select>` element.

I suspect that because of the `multiple` attribute, the element takes control of the pointer so it's list of options can be scrolled through. However, I am purposefully displaying all of the available options, so I'd like to prevent the scrolling override behavior somehow.

I noticed `-webkit-appearance: listbox;` is used for the select multiple, whereas it is `menulist` for a single select. I tried playing around with the `pointer-events` CSS attribute, but it causes the option list to become unselectable.

Any suggestions, other than converting to radio buttons?

**Update**
Thanks to btevfik, I now notice the issue is directly attributed to the form having a fixed height with scrolling overflow.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior from happening on overflowed content?

Forked Fidddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tv8ZT/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to override the default mousewheel behavior of the `select[multiple]` elements to scroll the overflowed element appropriately, without having to modify the DOM structure.

After the DOM has been loaded:

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName( 'select' );
for( var i = 0, len = selects.length; i < len; ++i )
{
    if( selects[ i ].hasAttribute( 'multiple' ) )
    {
        selects[ i ].onmousewheel = function( event )
        {
            event.preventDefault( );
            this.form.scrollTop -= event.wheelDelta;
        };
    }
}
```

There may be some additional requirements for full browser compatibility--like using `event.detail` instead of `event.wheelDelta`--but for my purposes this will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the 'size' attribute?

```
<select multiple size="8">
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tv8ZT/2/

Comment: Hmm...your example does indeed work, so something else in my code must be causing this behavior.

Comment: I'd prefer to use code that validates. After balancing the tags properly, the issue remains http://jsfiddle.net/tv8ZT/6/

Comment: While, theoretically, that does work, it is simply a hack that doesn't actually stop the behavior. It simply assumes the content after the `form` is large enough to scroll the `select` out from underneath the cursor and has a side effect of creating multiple scrollbars. http://jsfiddle.net/tv8ZT/8/

Comment: why do you need overflow-auto on the form then, simply remove it

Comment: The design calls for it to be contained within a scrollable area. Pretend I can't change the HTML code and can only use CSS or JavaScript to resolve the problem.